# Push notification on Android - not GCM

Tags: android, push-notification

I need a tutorial for push notifications on android systems.
I don't need an implementation of GCM, I just need push notifications called by an alarm manager of an app.

Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt that what you want would be described as "push notifications" on any platform.

Comment: Yes, the thing, I wanted, are just "notifications".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also refer [scheduling-repeatable-android-notification-in-different](http://blog.essencework.com/post/3622739193/scheduling-repeatable-android-notification-in-different)

For using AlaramManager, first we need to declare the BroadcastReceiver in Manifest file as,

receiver android:name=".TimeAlarm" />

```
public class CustomAlarm extends Activity {

     AlarmManager am;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      setOneTimeAlarm();
     }

     public void setOneTimeAlarm() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
      am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
     }

     public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
     }

    }


    public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

     NotificationManager nm;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      nm = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      CharSequence from = "Nithin";
      CharSequence message = "Crazy About Android...";
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        new Intent(), 0);
      Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
        "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
      notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
      nm.notify(1, notif);
     }
    }
```

Comment: The notification part helped me. Thanks a lot!